# Codeigniter: How to pass array from controller to view without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, codeigniter

Basically I have a form in the view with one input enabled, and multiple inputs disabled (only to show information derivated from the unique input).

Now, I need to send this input to the controller to make a query, and send back to the view an array with the fields information but without refresh the site (because I cant loose the progress that I have in this page).

Maybe the solution is to use javascript to send the controller the input field, and in the function return the array of values to refresh the form, but how?

EDIT: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: hint: its tagged on your question

Comment: Of course, But my knowledge of javascript, ajax or json are minimal, I know that Its possible, but I not know how to do that.

Comment: Do you have any javascript code so far?

Comment: have you searched any tutorials (`codeigniter ajax php`). here's [one](http://blog.alysson.net/lang/en-us/tutorial-ajax-com-jquery-e-codeigniter-php-frameworktutorial-ajax-with-jquery-and-codeigniter-php-framework/)

Comment: @Ziinloader yes, It is an extremely long form. Basically, In one part of the form I need to fill the user data based on the id you enter in the editable field.

Comment: Jquery ajax makes it so easy to communicate with your conroller for data inquiry to populate the page with.

Comment: [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples) and [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) these will make easy your life

Comment: @Ziinloader ups, sorry. I read html code hahaha. No, I dont have any javascript code until now. Im reading the kevinabelita tutorial, I had been looking for a tutorial that clearly explain this. Im trying to do in the way which is explained in this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I understand how to pass the array from the controller to the view dynamically, this is the code:

The view javascript:

```
function getClient(){
if($('#cedula_cliente').val()){
    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/clientes/getClienteFactura'?>",
        cache: false,
        data : {cedula :  $('#cedula_cliente').val()},
        success : function(json){
            var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(json);
            if(obj[0]){
                $('#nombre_cliente').val(obj[0].nombre);
                $('#apellido1_cliente').val(obj[0].apellido1);
                $('#apellido2_cliente').val(obj[0].apellido2);
                $('#dir_cliente').val(obj[0].dir);
            }else{
                alert("Usuario no encontrado");
            }

        },
    });
}else{
    alert("Debe ingresar una cédula de usuario");
}
```

}

Im using obj[0] because "cedula" is the primary key and It never will return more than 1 row.

And this is the controller function:

```
public function getClienteFactura(){
    $cedula = $this->input->post('cedula');

    $query = $this->Client_model->getClientByCedula($cedula);
    echo json_encode($query); 
}
```

Thanks for the answers, maybe I should have looked better on google, the key to solve the problem was Json.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = $('#input').val();
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: <?php echo base_url().'controllername/action'?>
        data: {input : input},
        success: function(data){
        // this data should be contain an arra
        $('#where_to_insert_array').html();
         }


 });
```

- In controller action and in action

  function action()
  {
  $data = $this->input->post('input');
- get data from database on $data
- make its array and then echo it

  echo array();
  }